# Stretchable form doesn't work in IE with absolute inside relative positioning and overflow

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, css-float

I'm working on an email-picker form that needs to be able to stretch to the size of the container, and also accomodate the "to" selector increasing in size as more addresses are selected.  I have a solution that works great in Firefox and Chrome, but fails in IE9 & IE10.

Here is an illustration of what I'm trying to do:
[image]

The core of the issue is that a DIV must be "position:absolute" for "overflow-y:auto" to work, and to position that within the flow, it needs a parent that is "position:relative".  I'm using tables in order to get the sizing to stretch properly in both directions, but bonus points to anyone who can make this stretch properly without the use of tables.

I have boiled down the problem to a minimal example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/yh7YD/4/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <table border="1">
        <tr class="first-row">
            <td class="to-label">To:</td>
            <td class="input-wrapper">
                <textarea></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="results-row">
            <td colspan="2" class="results-wrapper">
                <div class="results">
                    <ul>
                        <li>one</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    bottom:50px;
}
.first-row {
    height:10px;
}
.results-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
.results {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and [html5shiv.js](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/tree/master/src). When it comes to IE, these two have helped me a lot in making the things work. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though this is a bit of a general answer.  I tried incorporating both of these (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/EstHt/2/) and no dice.  Please note that this is not just an compatibility issue with older IE browsers, even IE10 in standards mode will produce the same behavior.  And I have also verified that it is not just a bug in IE10.  IE9 proper displays the same behavior.